# iOS Checking if a remote server plist file is a a new version than the locally stored one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, plist

I'm looking at using a plist to hold some data for my iPhone Application, as the data is small and does not require any filtering / sorting etc the plist seems like the easiest option for me.

Currently I am downloading the plist from the web server each time the app is launched however I would like to only download the plist if it is newer than the locally stored plist file.

Current I thinking of doing the following but was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
App Launch
Is Internet Available
    remote_Version = Download MY_SERVER_URL\Version.txt
    If local_version < remote_version
        file = Download MY_SERVER_URL\data.plist
        write plist to disk
    end if
end if
```

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to change the serving of the file from the web server, I'd recommend you take a look at the HTTP status codes. Specifically, your web server would ideally return a **304 Not Modified** if the file has not been updated. This removes the need to first check a version file. To do this correctly, you could pass the version of the last file downloaded and saved with the request.

Comment: This sounds like a better option and we do have control to change the way files are served up from the web server. Do you have any pointers to how we could get the server to return a 304?  Thanks Aaron

Comment: @FlankPlan That depends on what web server you are running. You will most likely need a server side language (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc). Each language will differ in how you implement this.

Comment: Thanks it's PHP I will try and do some searching on the web on how to do this, thanks again for the help.